# Localized description, english screenshots

Tags: ios, localization, app-store, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

Suppose I have an iOS application in App Store. I want to add a localized description but I have no localized screenshots for this language. The app is localized itself but it's a little difficult to make a screenshot set for every language.

What if I upload English screenshots for every localized description? Is it legal? Will Apple reject my app or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found apps that has more localized descriptions and english screenshots for all of them, for example, Evernote, Facebook, Twitter, etc. Nobody does localized screenshots. So I see it's legal and will use english screenshots everywhere.

[image: Evernote portugese]

Comment: Is this still true? I mean do these apps still not have localized screenshots?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is fine. When you add another language, the only things that Apple leaves blank are description and keywords. You begin a new language with the default screenshots. You can choose to keep them or change them.